# Cannot change device of pytorch model

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to move my device onto a gpu. After running the function to determine if there is an available GPU, and determined there is one (see below)

```
> device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
> device
device(type='cuda', index=0)
```

When I call `model.to(device)` I get no change in the model attribute?

```
> model.to(device)
S2SModel(
  (encoder): Encoder(
    (lstm): LSTM(5, 32, batch_first=True)
  )
  (decoder): Decoder(
    (lstm): LSTM(4, 32, batch_first=True)
  )
  (output_layer): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=1, bias=True)
)
> model.device
'cpu'
```

Though I have read that you do not need to assign the `model.to()` calls back to the object, i have tried that too.

```
> model = model.to(device)
> model.device
'cpu'
```

Comment: AFAIK, `nn.Module` instances do not have `.device` attribute. Where did you get the `S2SModel()` class from ? Can you check the `.device` for any of its parameters (like `model.output_layer.weight.device`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`device` is likely to be a user-defined attribute here that is different to the actual device the model sits on. This seems to be the reason why `model.device` returns 'cpu' To check if your model is on CPU or GPU, you can look at its first parameter:

```
>>> next(model.parameters()).device
```